# Subversion svn:ignore on update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn, svnignore

I'm working in Visual Studios 2010 and Ankhsvn.

I need to exclude a few of my files from being Committed (which I did through ignore-on-commit in the Change log.)

How do I exclude the files from being changed when I update?

I've tried adding the svn:ignore property, but I keep getting errors thrown. Maybe I'm using it wrong... It shouldn't be this hard to completely exclude files.

Answer (score 4):

`svn:ignore` is a property on a directory that you set to specify that the given resources *shouldn't* be in version control - which doesn't sound like what you want. If the file is already under version control, SVN will *always* try to process it. The effect you're after (restricting `svn` operations to a given subset of files) can be achieved using the `--changelist` option. You can use `svn changelist` to create lists of files, then suboptions to add and remove files from that list, then you can pass that changelist to `svn up` to limit which files get processed.

Comment: Thank you sir! so the --remove property doesn't remove the file from the repository, it will just stop the versioning process?

Comment: `--remove` is just used to remove files from a changelist. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html shows an example of how to create a changelist and use it with `svn commit`, but `svn update` will work just the same.